# "Cannot generate PDF: The filename or extension is too long" while generating pdf

Tags: linux, wkhtmltopdf, nreco

I am generating pdf using the following method with NRECO.
but while i am generating, I am getting the issue "Cannot generate PDF: The filename or extension is too long".

I gave permission as everyone for the path where I am saving.
My sample path is "D:/PdfSample"

```
HtmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFiles(new[] {
                new WkHtmlInput(coverpage),
                new WkHtmlInput(htmlContent)
                {
                 PageHeaderHtml = header
                }
            }, null, path);
```

Answer (score 0):

`GeneratePdfFromFiles` method expects that inputs are local files (or URLs) and the path (or URL) should be passed in `WkHtmlInput` constructor. In your case, it seems you're trying to provide here HTML content itself.